# Print not found or -1

Tags: java, printing

I want it to print -1 or not found only when the pat it's never found in the given text.
How can I fix the code? It will always print -1.

Output

```
   Pattern found at index 8
    Pattern found at index 23
    -1
```

```
public class FindWord {

    public static void search(String txt, String pat)
    {
        int M = pat.length();
        int N = txt.length();

        /* A loop to slide pat one by one */
        for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) {

            int j; 
  
            /* For current index i, check for pattern  
              match */
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                if (txt.charAt(i + j) != pat.charAt(j))
                    break;

            if (j == M) // if pat[0...M-1] = txt[i, i+1, ...i+M-1] 
                System.out.println("Pattern found at index " + i);
        }
        System.out.println(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String txt = "AABAACAADAABAAABAA\n" +
                     "ABBBD" ;
        String pat = "D";
        search(txt, pat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep track of whether or not anything was found. If anything was found, don't print `-1`.

Comment: I would suggest to use the 'indexOf()' method from java better than reinventing the wheel . Plus as a safety measure check if the string to be searched for is longer than the string in which you would be searching then you dont need to check and simply return -1.

Comment: Unrelated: local variables should start with lower-case letters, and ideally be named something meaningful. Loop variables are somewhat of a special case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag that you set to true when a match is found. If it is false at the end of the outer loop, print -1, as no match was found.

```
public class FindWord {

    public static void search(String txt, String pat)
    {
        int M = pat.length();
        int N = txt.length();
        boolean found = false;
        /* A loop to slide pat one by one */
        for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) {

            int j; 
  
            /* For current index i, check for pattern  
              match */
            for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                if (txt.charAt(i + j) != pat.charAt(j))
                    break;

            if (j == M){ // if pat[0...M-1] = txt[i, i+1, ...i+M-1] 
                System.out.println("Pattern found at index " + i);
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
        System.out.println(-1);
    }
}
```